# Jquery Load(); - finding html portion not div?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery code.

```
<div id="result"> <script>
$('#result').load('http://www.mystie.com/speicificpage  #uniqueid li:lt(3)');</script> </div>
```

So far it works great. Is there a way to do this for the content withing h2 tags? meaning instead of matching to an ID can you match to what's inside an h2?

```
<div id="result"> <script>
    $('#result').load('http://www.mystie.com/speicificpage <h2> unique title</h2> li:lt(3)');</script> </div>
```

I have a page that is a series of ul and each have a title. I have separate pages that need to EACH call in a specific ul (as they are updated.) can I just specify or match the h2 title?

Comment: Are there list items inside the `h2`?

Comment: no... I was trying to use the next() but it's not working. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any jQuery selector after the URL. For example, to load the contents of the `h2` with text `unique1`, you can use:

```
$('#result').load('http://www.mystie.com/speicificpage h2:contains(unique1)');
```

Comment: Thanks Asad, the solution work.. but I think the problem is that the ul li is after the H2 not inside it...  so it's not getting the li..

so the html markup is like this
<h2> </h2>
<ul>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
</ul>

Comment: ok I managed to do this now I just need to figure out how to do a limit of three li $('#result').load('mysite/page h2:contains(id) +').next( li);

Comment: @user5288 Use `$('#result').load('mysite/page h2:contains(id) + ul')`

Comment: weird.. how come UL works but LI does not??? 

the LAST thing is that I can't get it to pull only three of the li's. I am trying `$('#result').load('mysite/page h2:contains(id) + ul:lt(3)')`

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you will have to ditch `.load()` and write some code manually:

```
$.get('http://www.mysite.com/specificpage',
      function(html) {
          var $target = $(html).find("h2")
                               .filter(function() { 
                                   return $(this).text() == 'unique title';
                               })
                               .find("li:lt(3)");
          $('#result').html($target.html());
      });
```

This works by getting the HTML and manually filtering it before inserting the target fragment into your page; doing it manually enabled full jQuery functionality, which allows precisely matching the desired header.

Comment: ok I managed to do this now I just need to figure out how to do a limit of three li



$('#result').load('http://mysite/page h2:contains(id) +').next( li);